# User based BitLocker Drive Encryption

Tags: windows-7, bitlocker

While Unlocking a Encrypted Drive.. It is possible for that drive to be unlocked for only the particular user and not all other users who use the system.

For example, there are two users... `User1` and `User2`, user1 unlocked a encrypted drive, now he locks the desktop and `user2` comes and open the system from his account. Now, `user2` also can access the drive which `user1` unlocked. `User2` must not be able to open the drive. If he has the password the the drive then he might have access but not before that.

Comment: can you clarify "now the user2, must not be able to open the drive when he logs in from his account."  What do you mean by not able to open exactly?

Comment: @edusysadmin, I am tried to make the question more understandable, please see. May be title is a little of course, please make necessary changes if you see any fit.

Comment: are both users administrators or standard users?  Is it that if user1 unlocks the drive than your goal is that user2 cannot login or that user2 cannot see the HD contents when logged in?

Comment: @edusysadmin, users could be either administrators or standard users, but the user2 should not be able to access the HD contents when logged in..........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your goals are not possible using BitLocker.  If an account has access to the system when the drive is locked Bitlocker cannot restrict access if the drive is unlocked.

Comment: What if the normal users are to be restricted rather than the administrative one

Comment: @starx - doesn't matter, any account has access to the system.  BitLocker is not looking for the type of account accessing the system but if the system is allowed to access the drive.

Comment: @Starx: Bitlocker doesn't know if you are a normal user or not because it turns on **before the OS**.  Bitlocker can't tell what kind of user you are because that information is still **encrypted**.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use Bitlocker.  You should use EFS.  EFS uses user specific keys to encrypt files/folders.  That is your best bet.

While it encrypts the files/folders, they are still able to see the directory listing.  To hide the directory listing, you need to use TrueCrypt.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but since my question is asking about BitLocker, I would like to hear about the solutions related to it.

Comment: @Starx - to be fair, surfasb is right. Your question is sort of like asking how you can use a bicycle to fly to work. They're both forms of transportation, but they're for accomplishing different things. You can, however, set up EFS inside of a bitlocked drive to prevent unauthorized access to files once the bitlock encryption is unlocked.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. You could look into using the "Allow BitLocker without a compatible TPM" option. This would create a key that is put on a USB Drive and is needed at boot to unlock the drive.

Give user one the USB key and they use it when they turn the PC on, drive unlocks.

User two doesn't have the USB key so drive doesn't unlock.

Of course if you did this to a system drive user two wouldn't be able to use the computer (I assume you're just trying to prevent other users from seeing a secondary drive?)

Also it won't if all you're doing is logging out and back in without restarting that machine.

n.b. I haven't tested this personally, it is purely from random internet sites and David Pogue's Win7 book.

Comment: @Jost, I appreciate you trying to help, but this really does not help. I am not concerned with who unlocks the drive, but once he unlocks it and then chooses to lock the system, the another person who is also authorised to access the system is able to see the unlocked drive. That is my problem